# Java/Gui | How can I create a new button in the JFrame-Bar

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm wondering if I can modify my JFrame-Bar with a fullscreen button like this:

[image: fullscreen button in JFrame-Bar]

I found this on the Win10 reader.

Is it even possible to modify or change your Bars apperance with *Java Swing*?

I know I can use the JDialoge to remove the minimize and maximize Buttons. But I dont know how to add one.

Comment: `Is it even possible to modify or change your Bars apperance with Java Swing?` - not really. The frame is not a Swing component. It is an OS widget so it is not customizable in Swing.